# How to add horizontal scroll to gridview created by dataTables.js?

Tags: datatables

I am using GridviewFix.js and jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js in asp:Gridciew for search.It is working fine.Now i need to add horizontal scroll.When i add, the alignment of row is not same as the header and footer.

I am using this.

```
        var oTable = $('#GridView1').dataTable({
             "sScrollX": "100%",
             "sScrollXInner": "110%",
             "bScrollCollapse": false,});
```